# Incorrect attribute value type System.String while updating data in crm

Tags: c#

```
  string result = "";
        string outputDecimal = AmountTobePaid.ToString("#,##0.00");
        try
        {
            Entity leadCourse = new Entity("pet_leadinterestedcourse");
            leadCourse.Attributes["pet_paymentstatus"] = new optionSetValue(6);
            leadCourse.Attributes["pet_amountpaid"] = outputDecimal;
            leadCourse.Id = new Guid(id);
            proxy.Update(leadCourse);
            result = "true";
        }
```

**i am getting error, value is not updating in CRM**

Comment: Please provide complete and varifiable information.

Comment: thanks for your response it was resolved. i am using Money datatype.please find below answer.

Comment: If you have found your solution please aproved as answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
leadCourse.Attributes["pet_amountpaid"] = new Money(AmountTobePaid);
```

*use new keyword for proper conervestuon *